# What if a law creates a dangerous situation?

Tags: japan

In Saitama (not sure of city or prefecture) they created a law that if a cyclist rings a bell at a pedestrian then they can get a 10000 yen fine. So if you are a cyclist and you down a pedestrian because they don't know you are there because you are scared of the fine so you don't ring your bell to let them know you are there and some pedestrians (or are children) erratically move so they might move too suddenly  close to the path of your bicycle for you to stop in time. Who is liable if compliance with law leads to damage or injury?

Comment: In my city in the US, the law requires cyclists give an audible warning (preferably a bell) before overtaking a pedestrian.  In practice, some pedestrians especially children will move erratically despite (or maybe even because of) the bell.  Not to mention, dogs, deer and other animals pay no attention to bells.  I ring the bell, but it does not eliminate the need to be careful.  So while disagreeing with the Japanese law, I do not agree with the assertion that the law "creates a dangerous situation."

Comment: Perhaps contributes to a possible dangerous situation. You don't ring for animals and if children don't immediately move aside or get hand held by parents then you slam the brakes on at some danger to you but otherwise you'd have to be stopping all the time. Caution doesn't do much. Most footpaths are narrow.

Comment: if a cyclist ran over your child, would you just accept that the cyclist rang the bell and the child should have stayed out of the way?  If a cyclist runs into a deer, there is no liability b/c deer can't sue, but maybe it is not good for the cyclists.  Dogs have a nasty clothesline trick they like to play on cyclists.

Comment: I would be there to supervise him or thoroughly prepare him to be safe himself. If a cyclist runs over your child because the child ran in front it, imagine if your child ran in front of car or a train. Blame yourself.

Comment: if toddlers were routinely walking in the interstate travel lanes, traffic would slow way down.

Comment: Unaccompanied toddlers walking the interstates  would be detained by the police or picked up concerned citizens.

Answer (score 4):

Not a full analysis, but a framework for thinking about it:

> Like the French Civil Code, the Japanese Civil Code only has a single
> provision on tort liability. Article 709 of the Civil Code states: "A
> person who intentionally or negligently violates the rights of others
> shall be liable for the loss caused by the act."
>
> Tort law was gradually developed largely based on case law, including
> cases on pollution. Statutes outside the Civil Code also regulate
> specific types of torts, such as the Law on the Compensation of Losses
> arising from Car Accidents enacted in 1955, the 1973 Law on the
> Remedies of Harm Caused to Human Health by Pollution, or the 1994 Law
> on Product Liability.
>
> In a 1990 article, Takao Tanase posited that the calculated
> structuring of governmental and legal processes, not a cultural
> propensity toward harmonious social relations, accounted for the
> persistently low litigation rate in Japan. In Japan in 1986, fewer
> than 1% of automobile accidents involving death or an injury resulted
> in litigation, compared to 21.5% in the United States. The litigation
> rate was low, Tanase said, because Japan provides non-litigious
> methods of assessing fault, advising victims, determining
> compensation, and ensuring payment. Non-litigious dispute resolution
> mechanisms, mediation services, consultation centers operated by
> governments, the bar association, and insurance companies. The
> Japanese judiciary also works hard at developing clear, detailed rules
> that guarantee virtually automatic, predictable, moderate compensation
> for most accident victims. This contrasts with the American tort
> system, where the legal rules concerning both liability and
> non-economic damages ("pain and suffering") are stated in general
> terms, leaving a great deal to the judgment of constantly rotating lay
> juries—which in turn makes courtroom outcomes variable and difficult
> to predict.
>
> The result was a system that is vastly more efficient and reliable in
> delivering compensation than the American tort system. Tanase
> estimated that legal fees comprised only 2% of the total compensation
> paid to injured persons. In the United States in the late 1980s,
> according to two big studies of motor vehicle accident tort claims
> (not just lawsuits), payments to lawyers equaled 47% of the total
> personal injury benefits paid by insurers. This expense drives up the
> cost of insurance to the point that huge numbers of drivers are
> uninsured or under-insured, which means that victims of their
> negligent driving will get little or nothing from the tort system.

([Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Japan))

So, getting to the question:

> if you are a cyclist and you down a pedestrian because they don't know
> you are there because you are scared of the fine so you don't ring
> your bell to let them know you are there and some pedestrians (or are
> children) erratically move so they might move too suddenly close to
> the path of your bicycle for you to stop in time.
>
> Who is liable if compliance with law leads to damage or injury?

In Japan, the person who was hurt would promptly be taken to a local hospital, quite likely by the person who caused the harm or a completely unrelated bystander. But, since Japan has national health insurance and very affordable hospital pricing even to the insurer, the economic impact of the accident, even if the injuries were serious, would be much smaller than in the case of a comparable accident in the United States.

No one would sue.

But, the bicycle rider would apologize repeatedly, and would promptly and diligently pay some moderate compensation to the person harmed. The amount paid would be a bit more than amount of the exclusively economic part of the harm (excluding health insurance payments that it was forced to make as a result of the accident) that were caused by the accident to the person who was hurt.

No one would consider the impact of the government regulation as something relevant to justice between the people who were involved in the accident. But people who saw it happen might start having discussions with people in the vicinity and influential people in local government about whether this law was a good idea.

It is possible that the law would be changed as a result of this incident and similar ones. But, it is even more likely that the police would unofficially make it known that in some circumstances they will neglect violations of this law when doing so helps to prevent an accident if the person doing so tries to be polite in the process and apologizes for doing so.

The local authorities and people informally in the area, might also, or instead, probably encourage bicyclists to call out vocally in a loud but civil voice: "Excuse me good person, I'm coming behind you", rather than ringing a bell, which would be even more effective at preventing an accident. It is quite likely that this scenario was the intended effect of the local law.

Comment: People do sue. A child passed an elderly woman carrying heavy bags and she got injured. The child apologized.  The court ordered payout was 30000 yen against her parents.  Japanese are litigious- civil courts are packed. Excuse me "which good person" my way home and back is pretty busy with pedestrian. Roads are not good because of the drivers on idling stop.

Comment: @user2617804 It isn't that people never sue, they do so rarely compared to most other countries (relative to population) and aren't nearly as litigious. And a court ordered payment of 30000 yen (about $300 USD) suggests that the suit wasn't really about money - a Japanese litigation attorney costs more than that for a single hour. Since there is less litigation Japan has far fewer litigation lawyers per capita and less civl court capacity. Japan certainly isn't perfect and does have traffic issues, but the Japanese are not relatively speaking litigious.